# In which cases does printf return a negative value?

Tags: c++, c, glibc, libc

I'v been working on my own version of printf for educational purposes and while reading the manual I read that the function can return negative value when facing an error.

At first I believed that it returns -1 / negative value when an error occurs in the format string but this is not the case.

I began to think that it returns -1 when it encounters some syscall error and doesn't succeed in writing to the file descriptor, then I tested this code to check this idea:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    errno = 0;
    int stdout2 = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    int ret = printf("Hey", "Hello");
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\t%s\n", ret, strerror(errno));
}
```

It outputted:

```
3       Bad file descriptor
```

Errno is set, there is actually an error (the file descriptor is close) but no negative values are outputted.

I'm on Linux and use the glibc, but I also encountered this case in MacOS.
Any idea?

Comment: It's a bug? You might be the first C programmer in history to check the return value of `printf()`. I never did. Or else it was the `close()` that failed. Check that.

Comment: I heard this can happen on some systems (with `sprintf` as well) if it's a UTF-8 locale and the characters are invalid UTF-8

Comment: @KenWhite You can close them all. I don't know what 'not yours to close' could possibly mean. The process owns all its file descriptors, by definition.

Comment: Isn't closing `std*` handles a standard pattern in daemons?

Comment: @selbie And redirecting them in shells.

Comment: Also, why is the answer not anything but "by design"?  Op closed stdout, which the CRT is still going to reference directly.  The dup'd handle will have an entirely different value.

Comment: @selbie I don't see the point or relevance of the `dup()` at all actually.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne - I suspect that the OP thought by dup'ing the handle, printf would still work.  That's all I'm calling out.

Comment: @OP Please explain that to us.

Comment: `printf()` will return a negative value if it *detects* an error.   You're using unix/posix functions to affect the stream, and `printf()` is not really guaranteed to be able to detect those effects.   Try using ways of closing that are specified in C and/or C++ standards, such as `fclose()` (not `close()` which is unix/posix specific) or reopening `stdout` using `freopen()` as a valid but read-only stream (so it cannot be written).   Then `printf()` will have a fighting chance of detecting an error, and therefore returning a negative value.

Comment: @Peter I just wanted to point out that `freopen`ing `stdout` as a read-only stream is implementation-defined: `It is implementation-defined which changes of mode are permitted (if any), and under what circumstances` (C17:7.21.5.4).

Answer (score 2):

> In which case printf return a negative value?

The C standard says (C99 draft):

> The printf function returns the number of characters transmitted, or **a negative value if
> an output or encoding error occurred**

The POSIX standard says:

> If an output error was encountered, these functions shall return a negative value and set errno to indicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

So i read all your comments and thanks to Peter i closed stdoud like this

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    errno = 0;
    fclose(stdout);
    int ret = printf("Hey", "Hello");
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\t%s\n", ret, strerror(errno));
}
```

And it finally returns -1. But i'm surprised that printf does'nt check the values of system calls and threat them as error when they are (because when i close the file descriptor directly the printf does'nt work and set errno to Bad File Descriptor but return the number of characters and not an error).
Thanks for all of your answers ! And sorry if i left some messy code i was just testing at 4am haha.

Comment: How could it possible return -1 *without* checking the values of system calls?

Comment: Honnestly I don't know. For this case I think it check if the FILE struct of stdout is open.

Comment: I will try to recheck that this evening !